# Counting Excel Table Rows that are populated with data on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So im currently working a table in excel that I have named Table1 with three columns (Column 1, Column 2 and Column 3). Ive been trying to count the used rows or populated rows inside the table using VBA but have had no luck.

Example 1:

```
UsedRows= Sheets ("Sheet1").ListObjects.("Table1[#Column 1]").UsedRange.ListRows.Count
```

Example 2 (This One Returns only all available rows)

```
UsedRows= Sheets ("Sheet1").ListObjects.("Table1[#Column 1]").ListRows.Count
```

I either want the populated or unpolulated row amount. Either of the two will work just fine. Remember this is a Table so End(xlUp) and End(xlDown) work a little bit different. Ive tried those too but I still get either the total rows available or the cells that are modified which is way more than what I have available.

Thanks for the help in adavanced whoever posts.

Comment: Are you trying to get the last row, or the populated rows? You can use `CountA` for the latter.

Comment: Is an unpopulated row one with nothing in it, as opposed to having any blanks?

Comment: @BigBen the amount of populated rows

Comment: @SJR Yes one without any type of data/value in it

Comment: @BigBen I tried the CountA but its says this object doesnt support property or method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you can use `CountA`, like this perhaps:

```
Dim myColumn As ListColumn
Set myColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Column 1")

Dim UsedRows As Long
UsedRows = Application.CountA(myColumn.DataBodyRange)
Debug.Print UsedRows
```

Comment: That actually worked!!! Thanks a lot I've been going at this for half of the week. I tried using .DataBodyRange directly in the UsedRows with ListRows instead of the actual column. Did you use the Application Object to call on CountA?

Comment: What also works: `Debug.Print Application.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[Column 1]"))`

Comment: You can use `Application` or `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: @JvdV yes, I personally avoid table references inside `Range` but yeah, same idea.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't have blank cells in other rows.** The 3 doesn't need to be hard-coded, this is just the number of columns in your table.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

Set r = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange

With WorksheetFunction
    MsgBox .CountBlank(r) / 3                  'empty rows
    MsgBox (r.Rows.Count - .CountBlank(r) / 3) 'non-empty rows
End With

End Sub
```