# vba count function

Tags: excel, vba, count

all three lines of code use the same type of syntax. if i am not mistaken, the each of the code should return number of rows from header until just before a blank cell.

Expected result from the image:
cntr2 : 1
cntr3 : 1
cntr : 3

Actual result:
cntr2 : 8
cntr3 : 2
cntr : 3

here are the codes:

```
Sub mengelear()

    cntr2 = Range("K10", Range("K10").End(xlDown)).Count
    cntr3 = Range("AC10", Range("AC10").End(xlDown)).Count
    cntr = Range("U10", Range("U10").End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox (cntr)
 

End Sub
```

[image]

how do i solve this. tried the syntax "Clear" and "Clearcontent" but the result is still the same.

Your help and advices are really much needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: [Range.count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count) returns how many cells contains the range. without checking if the cell is empty or not. If you need to count only non blank cells, probably you need to use functions like [COUNTA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) or [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: After trying out different methods from several posts includin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29639474/vba-counting-rows-in-a-table-list-object which I thought would do it, it was in fact https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000266/counting-excel-table-rows-that-are-populated-with-data-on-vba that got me to CountA but then @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns already got it for you. `Application.CountA(Range("K10", Range("K10").End(xlDown)))` should do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting Excel Table Rows that are populated with data on VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000266/counting-excel-table-rows-that-are-populated-with-data-on-vba)

Comment: @foxfireandburnsandburns thanks for the help and also the link attatched. Problem solved

Comment: @notus_panda yeah, that should really do the works. Before this i thought function counta and countblank are exclusive to excel. But thanks to you, by adding application. i can use counta and countif